# How to knwo when the return '0' or 'false' is an error or the same data on update?

Tags: zend-framework

Here is the thing, when we use a model to update any row, is the data array is exactly the same of the row data, the update function return false.
Ex:

> $data = array(
>
> > 'name'=>'Jorge',
> >
> > 'last'=>'Ferrari'
>
> );
>
> $tabelaTest = new Application_Model_Test();
>
> echo $tabelaTest->update($data,'id=0');

Assuming that the DB have a row like this:

NAME LAST

Jorge Ferrari

This will print '0'. Any idead of how to treat this exception?
Sorry if i wasn't clear enough, poor english user ;(

Answer (score 4):

In your example, if the data in the table is identical to the data in the update, then `Zend_Db_Table` will return `(int)0` letting you know that no records were updated.

If you are sure that the `id` you updated exists, then you can assume the data was the same and there was nothing to update.

If `Zend_Db_Table` was unable to construct your query you reference a non-existent column, or the connection to the database cannot be made, then `update()` throws a `Zend_Exception` based on what the actual error was.

If the underlying `execute()` call fails to run the query, whether it be using PDO, Mysqli, Oracle, etc, then `update()` will return `(bool)false` instead.

Example:

```
$data = array('name' => 'Jorge',
              'last' => 'Ferrari');

$table = new Application_Model_Test();

try {
    $result = $table->update($data,
                             $table->getAdapter->quoteInto('id = ?', 0);

    // Use === to compare type AND value
    if (false === $result) {
        return false;  // bool false returned, query failed
    } else {
        if ($result === 0) {
            // no rows updated
        } else {
            // 1 or more updated
        }
        return $result;
    }
} catch (Zend_Exception $zex) {
    // exception occurred.  Could not connect, bad parameters or SQL etc
    throw $zex;
    // or
    return false; // if you return false here and above, then you don't 
                  // know if an exception occurred, or if the query failed
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: NOTE Not found != failed query, i.e. assuming row id=0 doesn't exist, `update()` will return 0 not false.